# Focus window using VS Code API

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, focus, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension for Visual Studio Code, and I'd like to focus the application window using the VS Code API at a certain point in the execution.

I've been digging through the VS Code and vscode-node-debug source code trying to find the line of code where the app window is focused upon hitting a breakpoint but I wasn't able to find it, nor do I know whether this would work in an extension.

Comment: Debugging is abstracted away behind the debug adapter protocol (https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/). It doesn't know anything about the UI, and I doubt that there's any VSCode API exposed for this.